# Send value from select option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a select option like this:

```
<select class="sortBybUTT">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Sort by</option>
  <option value="1">Highest price</option>
  <option value="2">Lowest Price</option>
  <option value="3">Most Recent</option>
  <option value="4">Most popular</option>
  <option value="5">Discount</option>
</select>
```

What I'm trying to do is to send data to JavaScript every time I change it without a submit button.

After I take the data to create a URL and redirect with JavaScript.

Example: `data = Lowest Price = value 2: my_shop.html?sort_by=2`

Comment: Use a change event listener on the `<select>`. Suggest you study some tutorials on user events and form controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the onchange event.

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

```js
let element = document.getElementsByClassName("sortBybUTT")[0];
element.addEventListener("change", () => {
    console.log(element.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an event listener then get the data.

```
let select = document.getElementsByClassName("sortBybUTT")[0];

select.addEventListener("change", function () {
    let data = select.value;
});
```

These might help you out:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp
- [Generic way to detect if html form is edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959670/generic-way-to-detect-if-html-form-is-edited)

Comment: The above code doesn't work, because the variable "select" is undefined due to the fact that the select tag is using the **class** "sortBybUTT" and not the id.