# How do I detect whether a user has interacted with a form?

Tags: html, css

I'm quite surprised that I wasn't able to find anything related to this on Google.

The issue I have now is I want my form fields to highlight based on their validity, but ONLY after the user has interacted with the form. I don't want invalid fields to be red as soon as the page is loaded. I tried using the :visited and :focus-within with my form element, but the former doesn't work and latter doesn't do what I want.

Am I not asking this question the right way?

Edit:
I did come across `onblur` in my search but I thought there would be an intuitive way to do this with CSS only, turns out I was wrong → [Does CSS have a :blur selector (pseudo-class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703241/does-css-have-a-blur-selector-pseudo-class)

Comment: To do this you will need to use javascript and hook into the onFocus/onBlur event of an input field

Comment: You need to use the onblur event to detect that a focused element has lost focus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic way to detect if html form is edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959670/generic-way-to-detect-if-html-form-is-edited)

Comment: Interesting things come up when you paste the question title into google ;)

Answer (score 1):

just check when the users starts typing with the onkeydown event

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need an `onchange` event listener on your inputs. As soon as the input loses focus, the javascript function will fire. I provided you with a code snippet as an example.

You can also look for other inputs like `onblur` or `onkeypress` but `onchange` is more versatile as it will work also for select tags.

If you want to know more on DOM events, you can see the [w3schools documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).

```js
const validateInput = (e) => {
  if (e.value.length < 9) {
    e.classList.toggle("error")
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  border: 2px solid crimson;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="enter your username" onchange="validateInput(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can go about it:

You can use Jquery:

```
$('#YourElementID').on('change keypress paste textInput input', function (){
   console.log("Something has changed");
}
```

Achieving this natively with Javascript has alluded me for a while:

```
document.getElementById("YourElementID").onkeydown = function () {
   console.log("Something has changed");
}
```

To bind it to a function in a Javascript class you can use the normal `Bind(this)` syntax:

```
#Start() {
    this.htmlDOM.onkeydown = this.OnInput.bind(this);
}

OnInput() {
    if (this.previousValue != this.jqueryObject.val()) {
        console.log("Value has changed");
    } else {
        console.log("Value has not changed");
    }
    this.previousValue = this.jqueryObject.val();
}
```