# Send all data from form using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I got a problem with contact form that I created using Bootstrap. I need to create submit button that will TRY to send all data from this form using AJAX, but I have to do this without any of javascript frameworks or libraries (this is my homework for school so yeah I really cannot use them... ).

I have no idea how to do this without jQuery so any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="usr">Name:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Enter name" value="" aria-describedby="name-format" required aria-required=”true” pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\s[A-Za-z-'0-9]+"  title="firstname lastname">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="comment">Message:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group"> 
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 pull-right">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Similar question (Both JavaScript and jQuery are mentioned) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588263/how-can-i-get-all-a-forms-values-that-would-be-submitted-without-submitting

Answer (score 0):

Add id to your form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="idadd">
```

And use :

```
    $('#idadd').bind("submit", function() {
            $.ajax({
                type        : "POST",
                cache   : false,
                url     : "toto.php",
                data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
                success: function(msg){
            // code
                }
                }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Hum sorry its with jquery

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990729/simple-ajax-form-using-javascript-no-jquery

Answer (score 0):

find every value of element that you want to send.
for example:

```
var user = document.getElementById('usr').value;
var email =  = document.getElementById('email').value;
var comment =  = document.getElementById('comment').value;
...
var data = 'user=' + encodeURIComponent(user) + '&email=' + ...;

....
xhr.send(data);
```