# How do I extract form data in html with js

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to create a web app, and I need to know the user input from form.

```html
<form action="" method="get" class="settings">
    <div class="settings">
      <label for="length">length of character(s): </label>
      <input type="number" name="length" id="length" placeholder="5" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </div>
  </form>
```

I need the form to run a js func foo()
so I assume that I need to put it

```html
<form action="" method="get" class="settings">
              ↑
```

how do I get the value of id="length" and use it in `form action"foo()"`?

Comment: I think this post might answer your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588263/how-can-i-get-all-a-forms-values-that-would-be-submitted-without-submitting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the value of length with `document.getElementById("id").value;`

In order to run a js from form, you need to use `onsubmit=""` instead of `action=""`

onsubmit="" allows you to execute a js function upon submission of the form,
while action="" allows you to be redirected to another page/site upon submission.

Read more about [action="" in this site](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)

[onsubmit="" is here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp)

Here is a workable code based on your example

```js
function foo(){
  var lgt = document.getElementById("length").value;
  alert(lgt);
}
```

```html
<form class="settings" onsubmit="foo()">
    <div class="settings">
      <label for="length">length of character(s): </label>
      <input type="number" name="length" id="length" placeholder="5" required>
      <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: this works, but I cant get the data to a function without it having to refresh and loose the variable again.

Comment: you can add a preventdefault() method to the js
        function foo() {
            event.preventDefault();
            var lgt = document.getElementById("length").value;
            alert(lgt);
        }

Comment: alternatively, you can add "return false" into the onsubmit field
onsubmit="foo();return false"